Filtering DataFrames in a Django Dashboard
I am trying to build a Dashboard with Django... I wish to filter the dashboard with category, month and Year. The dataFrame is coming from python code than I am adding the charts with JS.
I don't know how to proceed to be able to filter it as I want.
views.py:
def get_expense_api_data(request, *args, **kwargs):

    sort_order = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']

    exp_df = pd.DataFrame(Expenses.objects.filter(user=request.user).all().values('date_created', 'amount'))
    categories = dict()

    if exp_df.empty:
        default_items_exp = [0]
        labels_exp = [0]
    
    else:
        categories['expenses'] = pd.unique(pd.DataFrame(Expenses.objects.filter(user=request.user).all().values('categories')).categories.values).tolist()
    
        exp_df['date_created'] = pd.to_datetime(exp_df['date_created'])
        exp_df = pd.DataFrame(exp_df.groupby(exp_df['date_created'].dt.strftime('%B'))['amount'].sum())
        exp_df["date_created"] = exp_df.index
        exp_df.index = pd.CategoricalIndex(exp_df["date_created"], categories=sort_order, ordered=True)
        exp_df = exp_df.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)

        default_items_exp = exp_df.amount.tolist()
        labels_exp = exp_df.date_created.tolist()
    
    inc_df = pd.DataFrame(Incomes.objects.filter(user=request.user).all().values('date_created', 'amount'))
    

    if inc_df.empty:
        default_items_inc = [0]
        labels_inc = [0]
    
    else:
        categories['incomes'] = pd.unique(pd.DataFrame(Incomes.objects.filter(user=request.user).all().values('categories')).categories.values).tolist()
        
        inc_df['date_created'] = pd.to_datetime(inc_df['date_created'])
        inc_df = pd.DataFrame(inc_df.groupby(inc_df['date_created'].dt.strftime('%B'))['amount'].sum())
        inc_df["date_created"] = inc_df.index
        inc_df.index = pd.CategoricalIndex(inc_df["date_created"], categories=sort_order, ordered=True)
        inc_df = inc_df.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
        
        default_items_inc = inc_df.amount.tolist()
        labels_inc = inc_df.date_created.tolist()
    try:
        net_df = pd.merge(inc_df, exp_df, how='outer', on='date_created')
        net_df = net_df.fillna(0)
        net_df['amount'] = net_df['amount_x'] - net_df['amount_y']
        net_df.index = pd.CategoricalIndex(net_df["date_created"], categories=sort_order, ordered=True)
        net_df = net_df.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)

        default_items_net = net_df.amount.tolist()
        labels_net = net_df.date_created.tolist()

    except KeyError:
        if inc_df.empty:
            net_df = exp_df
        
        elif exp_df.empty:
            net_df = inc_df
        
        net_df.index = pd.CategoricalIndex(net_df["date_created"], categories=sort_order, ordered=True)
        net_df = net_df.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)

        default_items_net = net_df.amount.tolist()
        labels_net = net_df.date_created.tolist()
        
    savings_df = pd.DataFrame(Savings.objects.filter(user=request.user).all().values('date_created', 'amount'))

    if savings_df.empty:
        default_items_savings = [0]
        labels_savings = [0]

    else:
        categories['savings'] = pd.unique(pd.DataFrame(Savings.objects.filter(user=request.user).all().values('categories')).categories.values).tolist()
        
        savings_df['date_created'] = pd.to_datetime(savings_df['date_created'])
        savings_df = pd.DataFrame(savings_df.groupby(savings_df['date_created'].dt.strftime('%B'))['amount'].sum())
        savings_df["date_created"] = savings_df.index
        savings_df.index = pd.CategoricalIndex(savings_df["date_created"], categories=sort_order, ordered=True)
        savings_df = savings_df.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)

        default_items_savings = savings_df.amount.tolist()
        labels_savings = savings_df.date_created.tolist()

    labels = {'expenses': labels_exp, 
              'incomes': labels_inc,
              'net': labels_net,
              'savings': labels_savings}
    
    default_items = {'expenses': default_items_exp,
                     'incomes': default_items_inc,
                     'net': default_items_net,
                     'savings': default_items_savings}

    data = {
        'labels': labels,
        'default': default_items,
        'categories': categories
    }

    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False) 

home.js:
let chartUsed = null;

document.getElementById("showExpChart").addEventListener("click", funShowExpChart, false);
document.getElementById("showIncChart").addEventListener("click", funShowIncChart, false);
document.getElementById("showNetChart").addEventListener("click", funShowNetChart, false);
document.getElementById("showSaveChart").addEventListener("click", funShowSaveChart, false);

chartInsToDel = document.getElementById("chart-instruc")

function funShowExpChart() {
    var endpoint = 'expenses/api/data'
    var defaultData = []
    var labels = []
    if(chartUsed != null){
    chartUsed.destroy();
    };
    try {
    chartInsToDel.remove();
    }
    finally {
    console.log('Deleted already.')
    }
    
    $.ajax({
        method:"GET",
        url: endpoint,
        success: function(data){
        labels = data.labels
        defaultData = data.default

        categories = data.categories.expenses
        
        $('#category')
            .find('option')
            .remove()
            .end()
            .append('<option value="">category</option>')
            .val('whatever');

        newSelect = document.getElementById("category");

        for(element in categories)
        {
            var opt = document.createElement("option");
            opt.value= categories[element];
            opt.innerHTML = categories[element]; // whatever property it has

            // then append it to the select element
            newSelect.appendChild(opt);
        }

        const chartEle = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext("2d");
        chartUsed = new Chart(chartEle, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
            labels: labels.expenses,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Expenses',
                data: defaultData.expenses,
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
            },
            options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time'
                }]
                }
            },
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false
            }
        }
        );
        
        },
        error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
        }
    })
    
};

function funShowIncChart() {
    var endpoint = 'expenses/api/data'
    var defaultData = []
    var labels = []
    if(chartUsed != null){
    chartUsed.destroy();
    };
    
    try {
    chartInsToDel.remove();
    }
    finally {
    console.log('Deleted already.')
    }

    $.ajax({
    method:"GET",
    url: endpoint,
    success: function(data){
        labels = data.labels
        defaultData = data.default
        
        categories = data.categories.incomes
        
        $('#category')
            .find('option')
            .remove()
            .end()
            .append('<option value="">category</option>')
            .val('whatever');

        newSelect = document.getElementById("category");

        for(element in categories)
        {
            var opt = document.createElement("option");
            opt.value= categories[element];
            opt.innerHTML = categories[element]; // whatever property it has

            // then append it to the select element
            newSelect.appendChild(opt);
        }

        const chartEle = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext("2d");
        chartUsed = new Chart(chartEle, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: labels.incomes,
            datasets: [{
            label: 'Incomes',
            data: defaultData.incomes,
            borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
            y: {
                xAxes: [{
                type: 'time'
                }]
            }
            },
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false
        }
        }
        );
    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
    }
    })
};

function funShowNetChart() {
    var endpoint = 'expenses/api/data'
    var defaultData = []
    var labels = []
    if(chartUsed != null){
    chartUsed.destroy();
    };
    
    try {
    chartInsToDel.remove();
    }
    finally {
    console.log('Deleted already.')
    }

    $.ajax({
    method:"GET",
    url: endpoint,
    success: function(data){
        labels = data.labels
        defaultData = data.default

        $('#category')
            .find('option')
            .remove()
            .end()
            .append('<option value="">category</option>')
            .val('whatever');
        
        const chartEle = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext("2d");
        chartUsed = new Chart(chartEle, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: labels.net,
            datasets: [{
            label: 'Net',
            data: defaultData.net,
            borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
            y: {
                xAxes: [{
                type: 'time'
                }]
            }
            },
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false
        }
        }
        );
    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
    }
    })
};


function funShowSaveChart() {
    var endpoint = 'expenses/api/data'
    var defaultData = []
    var labels = []
    if(chartUsed != null){
    chartUsed.destroy();
    };
    
    try {
    chartInsToDel.remove();
    }
    finally {
    console.log('Deleted already.')
    }

    $.ajax({
    method:"GET",
    url: endpoint,
    success: function(data){
        labels = data.labels
        defaultData = data.default

        categories = data.categories.savings
        
        $('#category')
            .find('option')
            .remove()
            .end()
            .append('<option value="">category</option>')
            .val('whatever');

        newSelect = document.getElementById("category");

        for(element in categories)
        {
            var opt = document.createElement("option");
            opt.value= categories[element];
            opt.innerHTML = categories[element]; // whatever property it has

            // then append it to the select element
            newSelect.appendChild(opt);
        }
        
        const chartEle = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext("2d");
        chartUsed = new Chart(chartEle, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: labels.savings,
            datasets: [{
            label: 'Savings',
            data: defaultData.savings,
            borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
            y: {
                xAxes: [{
                type: 'time'
                }]
            }
            },
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false
        }
        }
        );
    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
    }
    })
};


home.html:
{% extends "boost/base.html" %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}
    <!-- Main Content Area -->
<div class="content">
    
  <h2>Hello {{ request.user }}</h2>
    
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="container overflow-hidden">
    <div class="row gx-5">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card text-white bg-info mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
          <div class="card-chart">
            <a id="showExpChart">
            <div class="card-header text-center"><h2 class="card-title">Expenses</h2></div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="card-text text-center">{{expenses_total}}</h3>
            </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          
        </div>
        
       </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card text-white bg-info mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
          <div class="card-chart">
            <a id="showIncChart">
          <div class="card-header text-center"><h2 class="card-title">Incomes</h2></div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-text text-center">{{incomes_total}}</h3>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card text-white bg-info mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
          <div class="card-chart">
            <a id="showNetChart">
              <div class="card-header text-center"><h2 class="card-title">Net</h2></div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h3 class="card-text text-center">{{net}}</h3>
              </div>
            </a>
        </div>
      </div>
        
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card text-white bg-info mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
          <div class="card-chart">
            <a id="showSaveChart">
              <div class="card-header text-center"><h2 class="card-title">Savings</h2></div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h3 class="card-text text-center">{{savings_total}}</h3>
              </div>
            </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    <div id='app'>
      <div id='dateFilter'>
        <h4>Filter by month, year or category</h4>
        <table class='optionsTable'>
          <tr class='optionsRow'>
            <td>
              <select id='month' name="month">
                <option value='' selected='selected'>Month</option>
                <option value='1'>January</option>
                <option value='2'>February</option>
                <option value='3'>March</option>
                <option value='4'>April</option>
                <option value='5'>May</option>
                <option value='6'>June</option>
                <option value='7'>July</option>
                <option value='8'>August</option>
                <option value='9'>September</option>
                <option value='10'>October</option>
                <option value='11'>November</option>
                <option value='12'>December</option>      
              </select>
            </td>
            
            <td>
              <input id='year' name="year_to_filter" placeholder='{{year}}' type='number' min='1900' max='2020'/>
            </td>

            <td>
              <select id='category' name="category">
                <option value='' selected='selected'>Category</option>

              </select>
            </td>

          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    <h3 id="chart-instruc" class="text-center" style="margin-top: 10rem;">Click on the cards above to show a chart!</h3>
    <div style="height: 30rem;">
      <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
    
    
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12" url-endpoin='{% url "boost:api_expenses_data" %}'>
    
  </div>
</div>



<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'boost/js/home.js' %}"></script>

{% endblock content %}

I hope I would be able to filter... I don't know if it is easier to send the raw data to JS and then apply the filters with JS or if it is easier to continue with Python.

Per best practice, you want to do all logic related to data on the backend (adding, subtracting, groping, etc.), from that point of view, sending raw data to the frontend is not an option. Also, could you share your models and serializers to help us replicate the issue?

Please, see all the code here: https://github.com/GusdPaula/django-web-app
